# Iterating through Array using modulus operator c

Tags: c, arrays

I would like to keep a running average of a specified number by the user. I'am using new and old to wrap around the array using the modulus operator. I would like to do this with the modulus operator. But every time I enter 10 for N I cannot seem to enter a value at the first index again.

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[]){
   int DATA[M]={'\0'}, N, new=0, old=0, i, values=0;
   float total, average;
   printf("Enter the number of values to be averaged over (N): ");
   scanf("%d", &N);
   assert(N > 0 && N <= 10);
   while(1){
      printf("Enter a value: ");
      scanf("%d",&DATA[new]);
      printf("Buffer contents: ");
      for(i=0;i<M;i++)
         printf("%d\t",DATA[i]);
      printf("\n");
      if(values <= N-1){
         total += DATA[values];values++;
         average = total/values;
         printf("Number of values entered: %d\t\tAverage over: %d\t\t\tAverage: %.2f\n", values, values, average);
      }

      else {
         values++;total-=DATA[old];
         old++;total+=DATA[new];
         average = (total/N);
         printf("Number of values entered: %d\t\tAverage over: %d\t\t\tAverage: %.2f\n", values, N, average);
      }
      new++;
      new%=(M);old%=(M);

      printf("\n");
   }

   return(0);
}
```

Comment: You do you write such an unreadable code? it's bad for you, trust me. `values++;total-=DATA[old];` this makes no sense whatsoever.

Comment: Just a critique, you should space your code out a lot more than it is and you should add comments frequently. It is very difficult to read in the state it is in currently.

Comment: @EvanCarslake I don't know, but it seems some believe that white space matters to the compiler? they don't.

Comment: Correct, white space means absolutely nothing to the compiler. The purpose of them is to make your code readable, and for that reason only. It is difficult to follow when it is all clumped together.

Comment: What's `M` in 2nd line ? `int DATA[M]={'\0'}, N, new=0, old=0, i, values=0;` Using `new` for variable's name ?

Answer (score 4):

```
total += DATA[values];values++;
```

`total` is never initialized so using uninitialized variables lead to undefined behavior.

Comment: Why do you find such things? I suspect you too write code with unwrappable syntax. But good for you, +1.

Comment: It's not, I admire your effort, but really the OP should improve their coding style.

Comment: @iharob Yes sir he should